# Zip subfolders using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, zip

I want to zip the subfolders present under a folder using a shell script. For instance, I've tried to use a for loop such as the following

```
for i in */; do **commands to zip**
```

But it's not working as intended. What's a good way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Do you mean zip them individually, or all together into one zip file? Please be specific with your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a for loop, but I find it simpler with the `find` command. For example:

`find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;`

This will find all subdirectories that are present in the top level directory and perform a recursive zip on each of them.

Comment: My requirement is to connect to an sftp and zip the subfolders there. This command doesn't work for sftp.

Comment: @SivaRam That is not something that `sftp` does. You can connect to the remote server with `ssh` and zip the files using this command. If you want to do it all in one command just `ssh $USER@$HOST:/my/files 'find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;' && scp $USER@$HOST:/my/files/*.zip .`

Comment: Thanks Conner. But I have to use expect as i'm connecting with password. I have tried connecting through ssh and after changing directory, i have used the below send command and this doesn't work for me:
expect "$"
send "find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;"

Comment: @SivaRam can you post a screenshot of the error you're getting? What do you mean by `expect "$" send`. That doesn't make sense to me.